# How to convert GitHub file into executable jar file

Tags: java, jar, compilation, file-conversion

I need to download a source code from github and convert it into a .jar file which I can then use. I’m quite new with Java, this is really one of the first times I’ve delved into it so I don’t really know where to begin.

I did actually do some research on how to do this and I understand I have to import it into eclipse or IntelliJ idea (I have both) but being new to this department I don’t quite understand how I would do any of that.

The link for the GitHub project I need to convert into a jar file is here: https://github.com/lukasvdgaag/SkyWarsReloaded-Extension

If anyone could help that would be amazing thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

As any other Java project, you need to have the jdk installed in your machine and then compile the project.

Normally you build your project with a build tool such as maven or gradlew, which helps you to do all these tasks. But I see this is not the case. So you need to compile manually with javac and providing the classpath, etc.

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/jme-sdk-3.0-mac/UserGuide-html/z400007747176.html) will help you